# Blank activity with fragment not in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi my problem is that when I want to create a new project in Android studio and I want to choose blank activity with fragment is not in add an activity to mobile window. Any solution that help me to fix it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can find it once you go to the next page.
Just check the box saying "Use a fragment"and click finish.

[image]

Comment: With version 2.1, select "Basic Activity" instead of Blank Activity.  You will see the "Use a Fragment" checkbox as noted above.

Answer (score 5):

I found the [answer](https://discussions.udacity.com/t/cant-find-the-blank-activity-with-fragment/35598) while doing udacity android class.

Select "Blank Activity" then Next

Answer (score 5):

As android studio is being updated so now you can just select blank activity then check the box "Use a Fragment" on the next page. then you will have activity with fragment.

Hope this helps..
Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

With version 2.1, select "Basic Activity" instead of Blank Activity. You will see the "Use a Fragment" checkbox. Click on it, there you go...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with the Android Studio 2.3 (today the latest version), here is the process:

**Create new Activity:**

[image: Create new Activity]

**Tell the activity to use a fragment:**

[image: Tell the activity to use a fragment]

It worked for me. I wish for you as well.