# Blank Activity with Fragment doesn't have a seperated MainActivityFragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragmentactivity, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am new to Android development, totally new.
I'm using Android Studio and following a Tutorial to add the Facebook SDK in it. The tutorial tells that I should create a Blank Activity with Fragment.
But when created I only have MainActivity and I don't have MainActivityFragment like in the tutorial.

Where to find it? and How it can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand which of the following situation you encounter:

- If a fragment is not created at all, try to look at this - [Blank activity with fragment not in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258246/blank-activity-with-fragment-not-in-android-studio).
- If the fragment is created in the same file of the main activity, instead of in a separated file, then you should probably update the version of your android studio. In older version the default fragment is created in the same class of the main activity.